# Error Upload a file to a user document using a postman

Tags: file, upload, mendeley

When requesting a file upload, I receive a processing error and I can't find out why.
Can anyone help me?

This is the error

```
{
    "message": "There was an error processing your request. It has been logged (ID caf30aebb0dcb58f)."
}
```

at the image the headers in this record.

Is possible see this logged error?
How solve this error?